# file name matches filename in URL in php always returning false

Tags: php

I am trying to check if the page I am on matches the $file and if so then require a file. But even though I am on that page it always returns false and can not work out why because the page name matches

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
The URL looks like this:
http://localhost/localwebsite/user/your-questions.html

```html
<?php
$file = "your-questions.html";

if(basename(__FILE__) == $file) {
  require ("function/Fuser.php");
} else {
  echo "File name did not match $file";
}
?>
```

Based on response below and checking further the correction that works:

```html
<?php
$file = "your-questions.html";
if($file == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  require ("function/Fuser.php");
} else {
  echo "File name did not match $file";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to compare `HTML` file to `PHP` file, `basename(__FILE__)` will return a file that have `.php` extension, and not `HTML` that is the first mistake that you have made, try to rename your file with `.php` extension and you will have URL like this  [http://localhost/localwebsite/user/your-questions.php](#) and some PHP best practice recommand to put PHP code in file with `.php` extension

Comment: Thanks for your response. As suggested I have renamed the file with .php extension and the code is indeed inside this file so now the its checking
if file is $file = "your-questions.php"; However I am getting the same result of false on this page

Comment: I think I have fixed it.
I changed the If part from if(basename(__FILE__) == $file) { to
if($filename == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {

Comment: Thanks  yvesdaxmaz for your help. I added my correct that worked above

Comment: you are welcome